# Is there a way to determine which degrees of freedom are lost in a robot at a singularity position by looking at the jacobian?

Tags: robotic-arm, inverse-kinematics, industrial-robot

For a 6DoF robot with all revolute joints the Jacobian is given by:
$$
\mathbf{J} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{z_0} \times (\vec{o_6}-\vec{o_0}) & \ldots & \hat{z_5} \times (\vec{o_6}-\vec{o_5})\\
\hat{z_0} & \ldots & \hat{z_5}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $z_i$ is the unit z axis of joint $i+1$(using DH params), $o_i$ is the origin of the coordinate frame connected to joint $i+1$, and $o_6$ is the origin of the end effector.  The jacobian matrix is the relationship between the Cartesian velocity vector and the joint velocity vector:
$$
\dot{\mathbf{X}}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x}\\
\dot{y}\\
\dot{z}\\
\dot{r_x}\\
\dot{r_y}\\
\dot{r_z}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\mathbf{J}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{\theta_1}\\
\dot{\theta_2}\\
\dot{\theta_3}\\
\dot{\theta_4}\\
\dot{\theta_5}\\
\dot{\theta_6}\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\mathbf{J}\dot{\mathbf{\Theta}}
$$

Here is a singularity position of a Staubli TX90XL 6DoF robot:

[image: robot with joint 4 and joint 6 aligned pointed down]

$$
\mathbf{J} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
          -50     &    -425     &    -750      &      0     &    -100      &      0\\
       612.92     &       0     &       0      &      0     &       0      &      0\\
            0     & -562.92     &       0      &      0     &       0      &      0\\
            0     &       0     &       0      &      0     &       0      &      0\\
            0     &       1     &       1      &      0     &       1      &      0\\
            1     &       0     &       0      &     -1     &       0      &     -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

You can easily see that the 4th row corresponding to $\dot{r_x}$ is all zeros, which is exactly the lost degree of freedom in this position.

However, other cases are not so straightforward.

[image: robot with joint 4 and joint 6 aligned pointed at an angle]
$$
\mathbf{J} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
          -50   &   -324.52  &    -649.52   &         0   &   -86.603   &         0\\
       987.92   &         0  &          0   &         0   &         0   &         0\\
            0   &   -937.92  &       -375   &         0   &       -50   &         0\\
            0   &         0  &          0   &       0.5   &         0   &       0.5\\
            0   &         1  &          1   &         0   &         1   &         0\\
            1   &         0  &          0   &    -0.866   &         0   &    -0.866
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Here you can clearly see that joint 4 and joint 6 are aligned because the 4th and 6th columns are the same.  But it's not clear which Cartesian degree of freedom is lost (it should be a rotation about the end effector's x axis in red).

Even less straightforward are singularities at workspace limits.

[image: robot at workspace limit with no aligned joint axes]

$$
\mathbf{J} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
          -50     &     650   &       325  &          0    &        0     &       0\\
       1275.8     &       0   &         0  &         50    &        0     &       0\\
            0     & -1225.8   &   -662.92  &          0    &     -100     &       0\\
            0     &       0   &         0  &    0.86603    &        0     &       1\\
            0     &       1   &         1  &          0    &        1     &       0\\
            1     &       0   &         0  &        0.5    &        0     &       0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

In this case, the robot is able to rotate $\dot{-r_y}$ but not $\dot{+r_y}$.  There are no rows full of zeros, or equal columns, or any clear linearly dependent columns/rows.

Is there a way to determine which degrees of freedom are lost by looking at the jacobian?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not by merely looking at Jacobian but by looking at the [Singular Value Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition) of the Jacobian, one can see the degrees of freedom that are lost, if lost. Of course it technically somehow turns up to finding the null space but yet I guess it is somewhat familiar and easier.

For example let the Jacobian be:

$$J = 
\begin{bmatrix}
          -50     &     650   &       325  &          0    &        0     &       0\\
       1275.8     &       0   &         0  &         50    &        0     &       0\\
            0     & -1225.8   &   -662.92  &          0    &     -100     &       0\\
            0     &       0   &         0  &    0.86603    &        0     &       1\\
            0     &       1   &         1  &          0    &        1     &       0\\
            1     &       0   &         0  &        0.5    &        0     &       0
\end{bmatrix}$$
A Singular Value Decomposition of this is given by
$J=U\Sigma V^T$, where

$$U=\left[\begin{matrix}-0.46 & 0.01 & -0.89 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -0.02\\\\0.03 & -1.0 & -0.03 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0\\\\0.89 & 0.05 & -0.46 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -0.01\\\\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -0.97 & 0.24 & 0.0\\\\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.02 & -0.02 & -0.07 & -1.0\\\\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -0.24 & -0.97 & 0.07\end{matrix}\right]$$

$$\Sigma=\left[\begin{matrix}1574.54 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0\\\\0.0 & 1277.15 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0\\\\0.0 & 0.0 & 50.59 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0\\\\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 1.36 & 0.0 & 0.0\\\\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.34 & 0.0\\\\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0\end{matrix}\right]$$

$$V^T=\left[\begin{matrix}0.04 & -0.88 & -0.47 & 0.0 & -0.06 & 0.0\\\\-1.0 & -0.04 & -0.02 & -0.04 & 0.0 & 0.0\\\\0.0 & -0.24 & 0.34 & -0.03 & 0.91 & 0.0\\\\0.03 & 0.01 & -0.01 & -0.7 & -0.02 & -0.72\\\\0.03 & 0.01 & -0.01 & -0.71 & -0.02 & 0.7\\\\0.0 & -0.41 & 0.82 & 0.0 & -0.41 & 0.0\end{matrix}\right]$$

Now, it can be seen that the 6th singular value of $\Sigma$ is zero. Therefore, the corresponding (6th) row of $U$ is $$\left[\begin{matrix}0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -0.24 & -0.97 & 0.07\end{matrix}\right]$$, which shows the direction of singularity. It means the end effector at this instant of Jacobian can't move in this direction. In other words, the angular velocity $ω$ of the end-effector about the vector $\hat{n}=-0.24\hat{i}-0.97\hat{j}+0.07\hat{k}$ is not possible at this instant.

The corresponding (6th) column of $V^T$ is 
$$\left[\begin{matrix}0.0\\\\0.0\\\\0.0\\\\-0.72\\\\0.7\\\\0.0\end{matrix}\right]$$ which is the direction of the above singularity in the joint space, which means the above singularity is caused at the end-effector when $\dot{\theta_1}=0, \dot{\theta_2}=0, \dot{\theta_3}=0, \dot{\theta_4}=-0.72$ units, $\dot{\theta_5}=0.7$ units and $\dot{\theta_6}=0$.

Answer (score 4):

You need to find the null space, not just look for zero rows or full columns. And I don't mean the null space of *any particular* jacobian, I mean the analytic space of all singular configurations, given the closed-form Jacobian. Usually this occurs because of a [gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) (as opposed to just an unreachable state space)

Doing this in closed form is very, very hard.   But sometimes you can reduce the space a little.

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if I am wrong. Let's check if the Jacobian matrix loses it's rank (for example using Matlab or Octave). This should indicate the singularity. Then let's try to check the rank of sub-matrices of the Jacobian, to find which degree of freedom is lost.